# IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain() returns E_NOINTERFACE?

Tags: c++, com, directx-11, hresult

In the renderer I'm designing in DirectX11 I need to be able to create a swap chain at any time, however the method I use crashes right at the CreateSwapChain() call:

```
    IDXGIDevice * device;
    HR(d3ddevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&device));

    IDXGIAdapter * adapter;
    HR(device->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void**)&adapter));

    IDXGIFactory * factory;
    HR(adapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void**)&factory));

    IDXGISwapChain* swapChain = 0;
    HR(factory->CreateSwapChain(_device->GetContent(), &description, &swapChain));
```

d3ddevice is a pointer to ID3D11Device, fully initialized and everything, I tested it out.
description is a DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC structure, each field is filled out.However, the function returns E_NOINTERFACE.My system supports shader model 5/directx 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the UUID of `IDXGIAdapter` when you query for `IDXGIFactory`:

```
IDXGIFactory * factory;
HR(adapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void**)&factory));
```

Try changing that to `_uuidof(IDXGIFactory)`.